# cannot resolve symbol(context)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog, android-context, builder

As still very young in android. am getting this error on this line in my code: `new AlertDialog.Builder(context)`. The error I get is cannot resolve symbol(`context`).

please kindly help,

```
   case R.id.chk_clas1:
            //do stuff
            if (chk_clas1.isChecked()) {
                if(c1.equals("0")){
                adddate(txt_clas1);}
                clas="1";
                fdate=txt_clas1.getText().toString();

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                  .setTitle("Delete entry")
                  .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // continue with delete
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // do nothing
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();

            } else {
                txt_clas1.setText("");

            }
```

Comment: Alert dialog doesn't work with `Context`, where are you writing this code? pleas post your full activity..

Comment: @vrundpurohit okay i will now

Comment: Is their anything you have defined globally for `context` ? Please post your full code.

Comment: @user3367817 Use `new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())` if you are using `Fragment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you use context as a variable but you have neither declared it, or initialised it, hence the error.

You could define it (and initialise at the same time)

```
 Context context = this;
```

since this refers to the current object instance of a class and Activity is a Context.

if you extends activity than use

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

if you extends fragment than use

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
```

Comment: I extend fragment but you didnt complete that line of code you gave new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), .....????

Comment: Okay. Now I have completed that. Write getActivity() in that.

Comment: I tried to use 'this' but it does not work. context doesn't work either

Comment: @Magic_Whizz are you using in fragments ?

Comment: @Magic_Whizz use **this@youractivityname**

Comment: this is what I have and does not work: AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.create);

Comment: it goes red for .create

Comment: @Magic_Whizz dont use .create ? use like AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivityName.this);

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513919/android-alert-dialog-with-one-two-and-three-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `context` use `yourActivity.this`

because `context` is current class instance in my case

My Activity is `MainActivity` so I will use `MainActivity.this`

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
```

Comment: Sameer Ahmed, when i changed it to my activity, i got this error saying Builder(android.content.Content) in Builder cannot be applied to (Com.tracker.Tracking.this)

Answer (score 0):

try this,
   replace context with classname.this

Comment: when i replaced context with my classname (Tracking.this), i got this error saying Builder(android.content.Content) in Builder cannot be applied to (Com.tracker.Tracking.this)

Comment: is this a Activity class?

Comment: then try this,  fragmentClassName.getContext()