# Android align center or align right title and message in MaterialDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, material-dialog

i use `MaterialDialog` version `3.1.1` in [this](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) address.

i want align right or center title and message in dialog but can't find how to do this in doc.

i check this page https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/434 and somebody use `MaterialDialog.Builder` like this code:

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .titleGravity(GravityEnum.END)
                    .contentGravity(GravityEnum.END)
                    .title("چقدر عجله داری بابا!")
                    .content("این ویژگی در نسخه‌ی بعدی فعال خواهد شد! برو بعدن بیا!")
                    .positiveText("باشه. :(")
                    .negativeText("چه بهد")
                    .typeface("iran_sans_bold","iran_sans")
                    .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                            Log.wtf("+","shod");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNegative(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                            Log.wtf("-","shod");
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
```

but it seams builder remove in this version. how can i do this?

**Update 1:**
[`MaterialDialog`](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) support change layoutDirection base on android system language but i have different situation and i want change layoutDirection base on content

Comment: Use the [MaterialAlertDialogBuilder](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md) in Material Components library

Comment: i only need align text to center or in right side. because this library has very good feature, If it done, it'll be great

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with default Dialog. But obviously, you can start with your own layout on the dialog.

## Custom AlertDialog

This full example includes passing data back to the Activity.

[image]

## Create a custom layout

A layout with an `EditText` is used for this simple example, but you can replace it with anything you like.

*custom_layout.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingLeft="20dp"
              android:paddingRight="20dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

## Use the dialog in code

The key parts are

- using `setView` to assign the custom layout to the `AlertDialog.Builder`
- sending any data back to the activity when a dialog button is clicked.

This is the full code from the example project shown in the image above:

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void showAlertDialogButtonClicked(View view) {

        // create an alert builder
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Name");

        // set the custom layout
        final View customLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        builder.setView(customLayout);

        // add a button
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // send data from the AlertDialog to the Activity
                EditText editText = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                sendDialogDataToActivity(editText.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        // create and show the alert dialog
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    // do something with the data coming from the AlertDialog
    private void sendDialogDataToActivity(String data) {
        Toast.makeText(this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

## Notes

- If you find yourself using this in multiple places, then consider making a `DialogFragment` subclass as is described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout).

## See also

- [Android Alert Dialog with one, two, and three buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513919/android-alert-dialog-with-one-two-and-three-buttons)
- [How can I display a list view in an Android Alert Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43532478/3681880)

Comment: I know I can do this on Android without any library, but I want to do it using the library I mentioned(for mentioned library features ).

Comment: @peyman It's the Dialog. What features should be here?) You can pass in same way custom layout to the Material Dialog.

Comment: see [this](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/blob/master/documentation/CORE.md). also i use `Files` and `Color` library in `MaterialDialog` in [@afollestad](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) github. @afollestad (the creator of MaterialDialog)  done layout direction base on system language(i think this is very bad) but my app must show direction base on content(imagine a language tutorial app). i have no time for create my own design and temproraly done it with change manifest to `android:supportsRtl="false"` and `tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"`.

Comment: Continue previous comment: i think i do it in next version of my app :)